# JSON Parsing Error no value for variable

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am doing a mobile app which retrieves information from my own API. I am trying to get a restaurant details in JSON and parsing them to be displayed. here is the error I am getting:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@cf94aa3 time:148477558
 E/MainActivity: Response from url: {
              "address1": "Market Square, Smithfield, Dublin Dublin 7", 
              "address2": "Dublin 7", 
              "cost": 35, 
              "lat": 53.3489980000, 
              "lng": -6.2788120000, 
              "menu_type": "BBQ", 
              "name": "My Meat Wagon", 
              "offer": "Meal for 10\u20ac", 
              "phone": 53463267, 
              "rate": 4.1
            }
 E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: No value for restaurants
 D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

and here is the code I am using:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray restaurants = jsonObj.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                // looping through the JSON object
                    JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(0);

                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String address1 = c.getString("address1");
                    String address2 = c.getString("address2");
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lng = c.getString("lng");
                    String cost = c.getString("cost");
                    String menu_type = c.getString("menu_type");
                    String rate = c.getString("rate");
                    String offer = c.getString("offer");


                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    String mobile = c.getString("mobile");
                    // tmp hash map for single restaurant
                    HashMap<String, String> restaurant = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    restaurant.put("name", name);
                    restaurant.put("address1", address1);
                    restaurant.put("address2", address2);
                    restaurant.put("lat", lat);
                    restaurant.put("lng", lng);
                    restaurant.put("cost", cost);
                    restaurant.put("menu_type", menu_type);
                    restaurant.put("rate", rate);
                    restaurant.put("offer", offer);
                    restaurant.put("mobile", mobile);

                    contactList.add(restaurant);

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "address1",
                "address2","lat","lng","menu_type","Phone","rate","offer","cost"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.address1, R.id.address2,R.id.lat,R.id.lng,R.id.menu,R.id.mobile,R.id.rate,R.id.offer,R.id.cost});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
   }
```

Comment: The JSON object you are printing, `jsonStr`, has no node called "restaurants".

Comment: "No value for restaurants" there is no such key in your json object, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for parsing json strings.

Basically you need to import the library, create corresponding POJO and call for gson.fromJson(jsonStringToParseFrom ,YourPOJOClassName.class). So your doInBackground will look like:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    YourPOJOClass parsedResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, YourPOJOClass.class);
```

If there will be some parsing issues at gson you will get well informed exception of what went wrong and you will get rid off all the boilerplate parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

Many APIs don't return an array when there is only a single result. You'll want to use `optJSONArray` and if it returns null, check if it's a single result (using another opt method), if it is, skip the array step.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf230/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray-java.lang.String-